# Notepad++ - Merge all lines into one and add separator

Tags: notepad++, regex

So this is my situation: I have a lot of lines like this:

```
line1
     line2
              line3
     line4
```

And they all start with different spaces. What I want to do is merge all the lines in the document into one, but separate each one with some character, something like this:

```
line1 | line2 | line3 | line4
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

No regex required in this case.

1. Edit > Blank Operations > Trim leading Space.
2. Replace All "\r\n" with " | " (make sure *Extended* Search Mode is selected):

   [image: 1]

Comment: Awesome works perfect. Can I ask you if can do this operation but only with the bookmarked lines? Of course just the step 2. I see i can select them and then use the "In selection" checbox but I use the bookmark function to bookmark all lines that contains a certain word

Comment: Don't think that's possible directly, but you can use `Search > Bookmark > Cut bookmarked lines`, paste in a temporary file, do the above and cut-paste back.

Comment: Uhm seems not working with a macro, at least when copy back step.

Comment: What does not work precisely? And what does "when copy back step" mean?

Comment: When I do the operation in the  document 2 all goes fine, but when I try to cut the new line (witch is in document 2 and cointains all the merged lines), he doesn't record the "past this line in document 1".

Comment: I'm still a bit unsure of what you're saying. Please post a new question (with screenshots of the error if possible) clearly mentioning it's a macro-related issue, and posting the relevant macro code.

Comment: Actually, it must be `\s+`, in regex mode. It will remove spaces, newlines and tabs.

Comment: After starting with `\n` only I didn't recognize I had only `\r` left and Notepad++ also renders single carriage returns still as line breaks...

Answer (score 1):

As @Karan answers regex it's not necessary to solve your question, anywise you can use it to do it in one step and to avoid errors with different UNIX/Windows end lines (`\n` or `\r\n`).

To do so you can use the Replace All "\s*(.+)\s+" with "$1 | " with *Regular Expression* mode selected:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Actually, a much simpler way is to go to Edit/Line Operations/Join Lines.  It's a built-in function that works in one easy click.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This will not remove extra spaces.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I do it very easily.  Let's say I want to merge all my lines but separate them with a semi colon.

Remove any headers
Select from end of first line (hold shift key) to beginning of second line

Then Control H

This will bring up your Replace dialog box where the "Find what:" will be blank, and the "Replace with:" enter your separator like the semi colon ;

Then Replace All